# javamail java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, keystore

I am trying to send an email with javamail,
on my local computer when I run my class the mail is well send.

On the production computer I get an error :

```
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS (java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl))
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1230)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:378)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:271)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:91)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:76)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:94)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:179)
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:199)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:249)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1226)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1245)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:220)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:147)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:125)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:68)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:102)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:247)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:633)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.getDefaultKeyManager(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:150)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.<init>(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
        ... 20 more
```

in the security path there is these files :

```
68595 Mar  9  2009 cacerts
 2221 Mar  9  2009 java.policy
 9937 Mar  9  2009 java.security
  132 Mar  9  2009 javaws.policy
 2940 Mar  9  2009 _local_policy.jar
 2481 Feb 28 12:54 local_policy.jar
 2469 Mar  9  2009 _US_export_policy.jar
 2465 Feb 28 12:54 US_export_policy.jar
```

no trusted.certs files.

the production use the jdk 1.6.0_13, is it possible that some file are too old ?
Anoter detail every thing was working well in production until last monday (7/30) nothing changed in the code, and now I am getting this error .

It is hard to figure out what is wrong because I don't even know which file is problematic.
If you have any idea I take it !

thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly the problem was that a custom keyStore was defined by the admin :

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=xxxxxxx.p12

And it was missing this :

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be failing while trying to open your keystore file.  Normally the keystore file is named ".keystore" in the home directory of the user running the application.  If this file was updated last Monday, that would explain why your program started failing then.  Note that you can override the default location of the keystore file by setting the javax.net.ssl.keyStore System property so check that too.

Possibly the problem is caused by your trust store, which can be set by the javax.net.ssl.trustStore property.

More information is in the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization).